# ASP.NET MVC - How can I build an HtmlHelper that doesn't need to be Wrapped in MvcHtmlString?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvchtmlstring

When I use the build in Html Helpers, I can simply write the following.

```
@Html.Actionlink(bla)
```

But when I write my own Html Helpers, I need to block the encoding by wrapping it in a `MvcHtmlString`

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.CustomPager(bla))
```

Is there anything I can do in the extension method so that I don't have to worry about "not" encoding it?

Comment: sorry had left a reply but realised that this may have been razor syntax specific, so removed

Comment: yup, this is razor. in WebForms you can use `<%=` instead of `<%:` which is quite a bit nicer.

Comment: It's a big enough pain that I'm considering going back to WebForms View Engine instead of Razor.

Comment: reinstigated - just for the h3ll of it :)

Comment: why? once you learn the few quirks of razor  it will save you lots time writing code by not forcing you to write <%%> every time you want to switch to server code and makes your code much more pleasurable to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you can make the helper return a MvcHtmlString - i.e:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Css(this HtmlHelper html, string path)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(/* some code*/);
}
```

rather than:

```
public static string Css(this HtmlHelper html, string path)
{
    return (/* some code*/);
}
```

i don't know the razor requirements, so this is a blind stab in the dark answer perhaps..

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that's how it all came together, though it makes perfect sense.

Comment: yes, a flow chart of how all these bits related would be SOO helpful.. :)

Comment: marc - in particular, the interfaces between the helpers and the various interfaces on the views. i.e. tools on the floor appraoch